# ¿Cómo filtro valores de una lista con jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

Estoy leyendo el json siguiente:

https://www.europarl.europa.eu/election-results-2019/data-sheets/json/2019-2024/election-results/parties.json

Quiero acceder a todos los `candidateAcronym` de un mismo país.

Para ello, estoy tratando de acceder primero a `countries`.

```
curl -s "https://www.europarl.europa.eu/election-results-2019/data-sheets/json/2019-2024/election-results/parties.json" | jq '.countries[].candidateAcronym[]'
```

Mi duda es: ¿cómo puedo seleccionar que sea un valor concreto de `countryId`?

He probado con `jq '.countries[] | select(.countyId=="ES")'`, pero no me devuelve nada y me falta por añadir `candidateAcronym`

```
curl -s "https://www.europarl.europa.eu/election-results-2019/data-sheets/json/2019-2024/election-results/parties.json" | jq '.countries[] | select(.countyId=="ES")'
```

Comment: que dice la documentación ??? si en la documentación no dice que se pueda hacer mediante la url, deberás usar un parser o trabajar con el JSON de la consulta en tu Backend

Comment: si necesitas ayuda con el parser entonces deberás mejorar tu pregunta ya que no cumple con un código mínimo verificable para darte el apoyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar la sintaxis `.lista[] | select(condición)`.

En este caso concreto, indicando que `countryId` debe ser un valor determinado:

```
jq '.countries[] | select(.countryId == "BE")' partidos.json
```

Esto devolverá algo así como:

```
son 
{
  "countryId": "BE",
  "candidates": [
    {
      "candidateId": "BE01",
      "candidateType": "PARTY",
      "candidateAcronym": "CD&V",
      "candidateLongName": "Christen-Democratisch & Vlaams",
      "memberOfCoalition": null,
      "coalitionMembers": null
    },
    {
      "candidateId": "BE02",
      "candidateType": "PARTY",
      "candidateAcronym": "Groen",
      "candidateLongName": "Groen",
      "memberOfCoalition": null,
      "coalitionMembers": null
...
```

Si luego quieres mostrar solamente el campo "candidateAcronym", debes hacer otro par de pipes: uno para seleccionar "candidates" y otro para indicar qué campo quieres mostrar.

```
jq '.countries[] | select(.countryId == "BE") | .candidates[] | .candidateAcronym' p.json 
"CD&V"
"Groen"
"N-VA"
"sp.a"
"VI.Belang"
"Open VLD"
"PVDA-PTB"
"PS"
"MR"
"cdH"
"ECOLO"
"PTB-PVDA"
"DÃ©FI"
"PP"
"CSP"
"SP"
"PFF"
"ProDG"
"ECOLO (G.)"
"Other parties F."
"Other parties W."
"Other parties G."
```

Puedes leer sobre los comandos en [jq Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook).

Comment: Gracias por el cookbook. Me será muy útil!